# sqlite Dynamically call field names

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

I am trying to dynamically call a a fieldname that has a number that changes.  Example I have Hard4, Hard6, Hard8, Hard10 as fields and want to call them based on a roll.  I currently get a syntax error and I cannot find anyway to to fix in by searching stackoverflow :(.

Any help would be grateful!
CODE:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\sqlite\crapsdatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()

die1 = 3
die2 = 3

theroll = die1+die2
if die1 == die2:
    c.execute("SELECT playerName FROM player WHERE Hard? > 1", (theroll,))
    for row in c:
        for field in row:
            print(field)
```

Error:

```
    c.execute("SELECT playerName FROM player WHERE Hard? > 1", (theroll,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

This is using python 3 if that makes a major difference. I also tried putting the ? in single quotes...

Thank you again for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, it would be proper to use string formatting, either the [`%`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) kind, or the [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) kind.

```
c.execute("SELECT playerName FROM player WHERE Hard%d > 1" % theroll)
```

Note that you should never use string formatting to build SQL statements from user input. When dealing with user input, always use `?`-style parameter substitution.

Comment: So this one did it.  The others code returned all player no matter the value of the Hard6 field.  The user wont input the dice number but a random number generator will....  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The `?` operator will not simple enter text into the your SQL code. Internally Sqlite will additionally do some processing. As you, if using a complete plaintext SQL query, would put question marks around the text, escape characters, sqlite also takes care of this, when using the `?` operator.

You can instead just use string formatting:

```
c.execute("SELECT playerName FROM player WHERE %s > 1" % ("Hard%s" % the roll,))
```

Comment: Thank you dron!  Your code for some reason returned all players even if the bet was 0...  not sure why!  Thank you!